# Multiple antenna single rfid

Tags: arduino, antenna, multiplexer, rfid

I am using 134.2 kHz RFID reader module. My module has VCC pin (5V-12V), GND , TX(don't have RX pin, Module has one way communication) and reset pin. I need to use at least 4 RFID reader for my project. Project will detect the RFID tag then make some tasks with servos and then send the RFID tag and servo's situation to the internet. I did this project with 1 RFID reader.

I try to do this with 2 RFID reader module with `SoftwareSerial` but It is not working good. So I started to research about how can I use multiple UART.

I found multiple antenna and UART. Multiplexed antennas are really good solution for my budget too so I decided to go with this.

I read topics from forums but I couldn't see anyone do things (as example).

- If I make 4 multiplexed antenna for 1 reader module (maybe I need up to 8 antenna), Can I find from which antenna the tag is being read? Because I need to use servos. For example antenna A's servos are servo 1 and 2, antenna B's servos are servo 3 and 4 etc.
- I have not seen an application related to this subject, except for some vendors. I found this schematic for connecting antennas to the 4051. Is these connections are okay? (one antenna's pin to multiplexer input pin then output will go to RFID's TX pin.)
  4051 is not good for my frequency. I guess I need to find another multiplexer.
- Would such an application waste a lot of time reading tags? (RFID module has reset button it can read in 0.1 second)

[image]

Comment: Is this project working now? Would like to know more. Can each antenna log data separately into spreadsheet with one column for each antenna. Thanks

Comment: @CharlesHarris I didn't try :(